# Who is Domo-kun?

Tags: domo-kun

Who is Domo-kun? Is he an anime character or a manga character? I often see him in anime stores so I wonder if Domo-kun is an anime character or a manga character?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dōmo-kun is the official character or mascot for the Japanese broadcasting channel *Nippon Hōsō Kyōkai* (NHK). According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domo_%28NHK%29), he was created in 1998 and named after a pun on "Hello there!":

> Domo-kun first appeared in short stop-motion sketches on 22 December 1998 to mark the 10th anniversary of NHK's satellite broadcasting. The name "Domo" was acquired during the second episode of his show, in which a TV announcer said "dōmo, konnichiwa" (どうも、こんにちは?), which is a greeting that can be translated as "Well, hello there!", but which can also be interpreted as "Hello, Domo", and thus is a convenient pun (dajare).

His concept was created by Tsuneo Gōda to be a mascot. He appeared only in stop-motion animation originally, so it's hard to classify him as either "anime" or "manga". However, there was a (reportedly terrible) English-only manga of the character, called *Domo: The Manga*, published in the USA and Canada.

As a final note, and as you may or may not know, there has been a whole world of memes created from Dōmo-kun (including the [Grues on Uncyclopedia](http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Grue)). You can read more at [Know Your Meme](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/domo) (**Warning: [NSFW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_safe_for_work)**).